# How to extract the date and month(in words) from a date in datepicker in php?

Tags: php

I want to extract the `date` and `month` from a date in date-picker to display the date in number and month in letters(like for `03` it should display like `Mar`).

> example for this: 03/09/2016

I want to display the `date(9)` and `month (as Mar instead of 03)` from the date which is picked from the database.Can anyone suggest how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easy if you look at `date` manual of `php`:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
<?php
$date = '03/09/2016'; // your actual date
echo date("j M Y", strtotime($date)); // conversion into string format
```

Output:- https://eval.in/561036

here:-

```
j =  Day of the month without leading zeros (1 to 31)
M = A short textual representation of a month, three letters(Jan through Dec)
```

Note:- if you don't want `year` you can remove `Y` simply from `echo date("j M Y", strtotime($date));`

Answer (score 2):

The date() function formats a local date and time, and returns the formatted date string.

- **j =** The day of the month without leading zeros (1 to 31)
- **M =**  A short textual representation of a month (three letters)

**Simply use this:**

```
$date = "03/09/2016"; 

echo date("j M", strtotime($date));
```

**Result**

> 9 Mar

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date can be Parsed using the DateTime library:

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01 10:34:44');
echo $date->format("Y-M-d");
```

This would output `2000-Jan-01`.
All the different date output types are outlined here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php